# Data outside canvas not removed when using fadings with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, ghostscript, tikz-fadings

I have a weird problem and was able to track it down to the use of fadings in my plot. My workflow uses `pgfplots` for plotting my data and after compilation I use `gs` to convert the pdf file with some options. The later part allows me to have a consistent dpi setting in raster images regardless of any scaling I do within my document. However this reveals that the plot data is still within the document when `fadings` are used, sometimes spanning over a whole page in my document.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
 X    Y
-3    9      %  0 left out
-2    4      %  1 plotted
-1    1      %  2 plotted
-0.5  0.25   %  3 plotted
 0    0      %  4 plotted
 0.5  0.25   %  5 plotted
 1    1      %  6 left out
 2    4      %  7 left out
 3    9      %  8 left out
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[xmax=1.5,
            %restrict x to domain*=-3:1.5
            ]
        \fill [red, opacity=.125, path fading=north] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,9);
        \addplot table {data.txt};
     \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
text

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmax=1.5]
        \fill [red, opacity=.125] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,9);
        \addplot table {data.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
text

\end{document}
```

A conversation after compiling

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=300dpi.pdf test.pdf
```

reveals that the data is still inside the document: [image]

While `restrict to domain` might seem like an easy solution, this only restricts the data and will result in a wrong plot. Is there an easy way to use fadings and still crop the data outside of the plot?

Thanks!

Comment: One ugly solution would be to use two axis environments on top of each other, but this would fail on other use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what gs will do with this, but the fadings are not inside the axis environment.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
 X    Y
-3    9      %  0 left out
-2    4      %  1 plotted
-1    1      %  2 plotted
-0.5  0.25   %  3 plotted
 0    0      %  4 plotted
 0.5  0.25   %  5 plotted
 1    1      %  6 left out
 2    4      %  7 left out
 3    9      %  8 left out
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[xmax=1.5,
            %restrict x to domain*=-3:1.5
            name=border
            ]
        \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:1,9);
        \addplot table {data.txt};
     \end{axis}
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (border.south west) rectangle (border.north east);
      \fill [red, opacity=.125, path fading=north] (A) rectangle (B);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
text

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmax=1.5]
        \fill [red, opacity=.125] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:1,9);
        \addplot table {data.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem really seems to be related to the fading inside axis environment. Using coordinates is a nicer solution than two axis environments, thanks for the answer!

Comment: BTW, the scole and clip are probably overkill.